# Rich snippets for all schema.org data types?

Tags: google, rich-snippets, structured-data

The list of data types displayed on the [Structured Data Markup Helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/0/) is limited in comparison to what is available on [Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/full.html)

I am wondering if Google supports rich snippets for all schema.org data types as is possibly suggested by https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146645

Comment: Yes, if you click on the [Find out more](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158) link there and then click on _What is schema.org_, you'll see that it's a:  `collaboration by Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo! to improve the web by creating a structured data markup schema supported by major search engines.`

Comment: Oh cool. Do you know by chance if Google displays all schema types as rich snippets?  Or is there a limited set that is processed and displayed in the rich snippet format? Also, is there a guide to what Google considers a minimum set of data points for rich snippet display for each given schema.org data type?

Comment: Yes, no, and not quite sure I follow what you mean. As long as you follow the examples at `schema.org` and include the Expected Type for the Property, and your code validates in the Google [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), you should be fine.

Comment: Cool thanks .. What I mean is, if you create a Person but only put the name, will this be enough for Google to display a Person snippet, or is there more required.. etc

Comment: No problem. Likely so if you supply the Text for it and use the right syntax, you just need to test it with the Structured Data Testing Tool to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abram, I think this page might help answer your question:  https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/2643152?hl=en&ref_topic=30163  Google does limit which structured data markups they display rich snippets for, so not all markups will generate a snippet.

In regards to your other question about the person rich snippet, usually that snippet is generated through the use of the authorship tag, which is something completely different than schema.  For more on that, you can check out this page:  https://plus.google.com/authorship

I hope that helps answer your questions.

David

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the help. I was using Person as an example data type. Check out the comments above :)